# How to count and categorize values by the same criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with just 2 columns, the `ProductID` and the `Discount`.

There are many products registered in rows.

So, I want to know how many products there are in this table with the same discount, categorized by the discount column value.

How can I query this by the easiest and simplest way?

The view that I expect for:

```
Discount    -   QTD
-------------------
0.25        -   150
0.40        -   320
0.75        -   532
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a simple aggregation should do the trick.

```
Select Discount
      ,QTD = count(*)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Discount
```

Comment: John,  please. Could you explain to me when I should use (*) instead of just * ?

Comment: @JoãoPedroReisSilva If you want an aggregation, count(*) will count the records.  You could also use count(Discount) or even sum(1).   Select * .. will present all columns of your  query

Comment: @JoãoPedroReisSilva  Just for fun  try Select * from YourTable   ... this will return all records without any aggregations.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. But I also tried to use ''AS'' instead of ''='', but it didn't work.
Do you have some tip for this also? I'm sorry for these basics questions, I'm a beginner...

Comment: @JoãoPedroReisSilva If using the alias approach  it woud be   ... count(*) as QTD ...